# Using EDE for handling cmake/C++ projects in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, cedet

I would like to use EDE (from CEDET) to handle some of my C++-projects that are based on cmake. I found some information that this should be possible. But what's the best way to create a new project from existing source and cmake files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake-based projects aren't supported yet natively - I personally use standard ede-cpp-root project type + [some custom commands to compile code](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el#L130).
There is some work on more complete functionality in this direction. You can find changes in [separate repository](https://code.launchpad.net/~arankine/+junk/ede-cmake).